# What are these stars in my microscopic image?

Tags: botany, microscopy

I see this very curious patterns on the sun-facing side of a **jasmine** (probably) leaf - visible with a makeshift microscope (about 50x)

What are them? Pores? Are there other plants with similar textures?

The microscope is made out of a webcam, as described [here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/science/0/22600308)

[image]

Comment: really curious. What are these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite low resolution, I'd say those are trichomes. *Jasminum* is genera that produce essential oils, so it have glandular hairs and other trichomes wich help to rettain the oil layer.

[image]

Source: http://cms.herbalgram.org/herbalgram/issue53/article2207.html?ts=1376643526&signature=b4349f7f3ca6f6a47823f4754237eaac

The image displayed above shows glandular and non-glandular trichomes in lavander shown by scanning electron microscopy. I'm afraid I couldn't find anything about *Jasminum* in particular, but I think it must be the same kind of structure.